# Can a quadratic matrix inequality constraint be convex?

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I have an optimization problem with a semi-definiteness constraint:
$$
N \preceq 0
$$
where the entries $N^{AB}$ of the matrix $N$ are defined through
$$
N^{AB} = \sum_{i,j} x^i M_{ij}^{AB} x^j
$$
The $x^i$ are my independent variables, whereas the $M_{ij}^{AB}$ are fixed and obey $M_{ij}^{AB}= M_{ij}^{BA}$ so $N$ is symmetric. The variable to optimize is a linear combination of the $x^i$.

When $N$ is a one-by-one matrix this is a simple [quadratically constrained program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program). In this case the problem is convex if $M_{ij}$ is positive semidefinite, and the translation to a familiar semidefinite programming problem can be found, for example, in section 8.1 of [these lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-251j-introduction-to-mathematical-programming-fall-2009/readings/MIT6_251JF09_SDP.pdf).

When $N$ is of higher dimension the constraint is similar to a *bilinear matrix inequality*. In [this tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/braatzgroup/33_A_tutorial_on_linear_and_bilinear_matrix_inequalities.pdf) it is simply mentioned that such inequalities do not carve out convex sets in general. However it seems to me that the problem can very well be convex for suitable $M^{AB}_{ij}$.

Question: can we think of constraints for $M^{AB}_{ij}$ so that the problem ends up being non-trivially convex? And what would then be the translation to a standard semidefinite programming problem?

Comment: should it be $x^i M^{AB}_{ij}x^j$ under $\sum_{i,j}$ ?

Comment: I actually would recommend the notation $N^{AB}=x^\top M^{AB} x$.

Comment: [A tutorial on linear and bilinear matrix inequalities](http://web.mit.edu/braatzgroup/33_A_tutorial_on_linear_and_bilinear_matrix_inequalities.pdf) (2000)

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo, that was useful. I have updated the question to include what I learned from the tutorial.